# Can I get raw access to the PS/2 port in Linux?

Tags: linux, serial, ps2, linux-device-driver

Context: I have an exotic keyboard with a screen on it. I believe that the host machine draws on the screen by sending commands down a PS/2 connection (I'm still reverse engineering the protocol).

My computer has a PS/2 interface. Being able to just wire the keyboard up to a plug would be incredibly convenient, but I need to be able to write bytes to the interface to make the screen work. Linux provides a `/dev/psaux` device, but that provides cooked output only.

AFAICT the 8042 itself is wrapped in a serio device with the PS/2 protocol decoded in the kernel by the `/dev/input` layer. I've found references to a patch which exposes serio devices as normal character devices, but it dates back to the 2.4 days and is now obsolete. (See [https://web.archive.org/web/20130726234145/http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~danlee/fun/psaux/.](https://web.archive.org/web/20130726234145/http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/%7Edanlee/fun/psaux/.))

It seems plausible that there's a way to bind a modern character device to the i8042 serio device, but I can't find any mention of this or how it would work.

Does anyone know more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely randomly I found this in the kernel configuration:

```
Option: SERIO_RAW 
Say Y here if you want to have raw access to serio ports, such as AUX
ports on i8042 keyboard controller. Each serio port that is bound to this
driver will be accessible via a char device with major 10 and dynamically
allocated minor. The driver will try allocating minor 1 (that historically
corresponds to /dev/psaux) first. To bind this driver to a serio port use
sysfs interface:

echo -n "serio_raw" > /sys/bus/serio/devices/serioX/drvctl

To compile this driver as a module, choose M here: the module will be
called serio_raw.
```

That is, I believe, exactly what I'm looking for. It does look as if this will disconnect the atkbd drive from the port, and I'd rather like to be able to send bytes while still having atkbd listen, but I can live with that. I'll update this if I find anything more out.